# Cannot test my AOSP build on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-source

I built the Android AOSP tree for the mako device successfully on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop with the '. build/envset.sh', 'lunch mako-userdebug', and 'make -j4' series of commands. I tried to run it in the emulator by following the Google-provided instructions (i.e. typing the 'emulator' command in a terminal right after the build is complete) but it does not work. The emulator starts up but is stuck on a black screen. I noticed the following warning/errors while the emulator starts up:

```
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Transport endpoint is not connected (errno = 107)
```

Any help in resolving this error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use virualbox to make a custom image and test : http://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/

Comment: Thanks, I may try this work around if nothing else is proposed. It just seems that the AOSP emulator should just work without having to resort to installing a virtual box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil,

To make an image for the emulator, you will need to make one of the generic images. e.g. lunch aosp_arm-eng (you can also us userdebug, etc). It may not show up in the lunch menu, but it should be available nonetheless. The emulator was made strictly to test the changes made in the framework and to the default system properties (those that are hardware independent). Building the arm version should fix your errors!

Best!